# How would you ask "Which courses do you have this semester?" in Latin? Specifically, which word would you use for "course"?

Tags: word-request

The English word "course" comes from Latin "cursus". But the Croatian word for "course at a university" is "kolegij", which comes from Latin "collegium". So, how would you say "course at a university" in Latin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use *schola* or *lectio*, or perhaps *auditio*. Typical expressions are *in scholam ire*, *scholam obire* or *scholae interesse*.

Therefore a possible translation would be: **Quas scholas hoc semestri obibis?**